# Copy question: What to call credential management

Tags: copywriting

I am looking for help deciding on CTA copy, for a button that launches the credential management page. This page will allow a user to update their credentials, the user can:

- Add a password (If one does not exist)
- Link a social provider, to use for authentication.
- Remove a social provider.

We currently use the term Sign in/ Join throughout the program so I'm stuck on changing the text to anything like Login credentials.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your audience, as different audiences tend to favor different language types (friendly, formal etc). I would considering specifying what is on each page as it can be confusing no matter how hard you try. For example assuming you have other options which can be changed you might have a list like this:

- Your details
- Login Credentials
- Payment Information

Now the user needs to update their email, well is that Login or Your details? How about address - that's part of the payment method? This all applies to your question - it is just a broader look. So rather than that, I would categorize them, and sub categorize them:

[image: List with sub list]

You can also see most big sites use this tactic for that reason I believe. Look at your Amazon, Google, FB, or Ebay account.

TL;DR **So I would say the answer is, don't worry about the specific language - as long as it is descriptive you will always have room for human error/misunderstanding - mitigate that by showing a little more to start off with.**